# Gimp shadow text not working

Tags: gimp

I am trying to shadow some text in Gimp. However, whenever I go to filter drop down shadow it gives a shadow to the region I previously selected with the selection tool on another layer. I have selected my text and the text layer. Why is it not giving a shadow to my text in the text layer?

Comment: I got it working somehow. I dont know why this problem showed up.

Comment: You do not need any selection, actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The classic `drop shadow` plug-in has actually two different behaviors, depending exactly on wether there is a selection or not.

If there is a selection, it creates a shadow os the *selection countour* itself on the current layer (yes, this is nearly useless). When used with no active selection on the image, it has the expected behavior of creating a new layer containing the shadow of the non-transparent areas of the current layer.